# Read two optional seperated integers with scanf

Tags: c, formatting, scanf

I am completely new to C. 
I want to read two integers with the `scanf` function, that are seperated by whitespaces OR by one comma. If the formatstring says `"%d%d"` the whitespaces are automatically  handled for me. But if I change it to

```
scanf("%d,%d", &firstNum, &secondNum);
```

I have to seperate both values with one comma. It should by possible for the user to enter *1,2* or *1 2* (no matter how many whitespaces are inbetween).
Is it possible to achieve this function with one call of `scanf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `scanset`

```
    scanf("%d%*[, ]%d", &a, &b);
```

1. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: Without checking the return value of `scanf()`, the method is of little value.